# Run two xservers on one GPU in headless system

Tags: xorg, nvidia, gpu, x-server

I have a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti in a Linux server without display monitor. Now, I need to run two xservers on this GPU to support two docker containers(each container use one xserver via different DISPLAY environment variable). But it does not work successfully. Here are my operations.

1. configure the xorg.conf with a virtual screen via `nvidia-xconfig`:

```bash
nvidia-xconfig -a --virtual=2560x1440
```

[image: xorg]

2. start a xserver with :0 display, and then run an OpenGL sample, glxgears:

```
Xorg :0 &

export DISPLAY=:0

glxgears
```

it runs successfully on the virtual screen and can use the GPU:
[image]

3. then I start a new xserver using :1 display:

```
Xorg :1
```

I found the glxgears can not use GPU anymore:
[image]

And the log of the first xserver with :0 display shows that the device is removed:
[image]

So, I want to ask two questions:

- Why the device is removed when the second xserver starts? Does the NVIDIA driver limit this?
- Is it possible to run two or more xserver on one GPU? How to do if it can be?

Appreciate for your help!